# Performance when showing/hiding elements

Tags: jquery

I was wondering about one common task that you usually have to do with each app at least once.
A task of showing/hiding an element based on another element. For instance a 'play' button when playing some media will be changed for a 'pause' or 'stop' button when media is playing and vice-versa.

Is it better (performance-wise):

1. to show another element and hide the current one (both pause and play button already in DOM with appropriate event listeners)
2. to change src or background and event for the button

I reckon option 1 is the usual one since there's more work for the second option? But is it also faster / more responsive? If you have LOTS of DOM stuff already, it might not be a good idea to put another 3 buttons inside if you can only have one? (for instance in my 'play','pause' and 'stop' case). Is option 2 too messy?

I was considering second option for when there is a list of items that each has all those buttons inside. I'll benchmark this myself if there's no one with a good opinion supported with facts about this.

Thanks for any tips/ideas/suggestions

Comment: Why not benchmark it yourself?

Comment: I will, if I don't get any answers from people who may have already done it. Why the downvote?

Comment: I am not the downvoter ... But it would have been nice of him/her to elaborate on the reason!

Answer (score 0):

my message got to long as a comment, so i post it as a solution... but it is NONE!
the following is all my personal thoughts and experience about the topic. this won't replace a serious benchmark.

i guess, this is completely depending on the content of the elements itself. 
as long, as it is something simple like a play/pause button i suppose, there is no measurable difference between both approaches, even with a lot of other dom elements on your page.
(at least, on my page it doesn't make a difference in terms of user experience)

if there is more content (like bigger images, wall of text etc.) inside the element: 
- a show/hide solution would be slower on load, since everything gets loaded, even if its not needed in the beginning
- and since it stays in the dom, your page takes up more memory on the user device.

on the other hand, the new content gets shown faster, on user interaction, since it is already there ;)

so i'd assume, there is no "solution" to which approach would be better. it depends on your page and you have to find the "best of both worlds" to fit your needs...